# Is it possible to filter a set of lines through an external command in ed?

Tags: ed

In `ed`, one can retrieve the output of a command into the current buffer by using `r !COMMAND`. One can also write a set of lines to the input of a command by using `1,3w !COMMAND`.

However, I cannot determine how to do both simultaneously.

```
r 1,3w !sort
1,3w !sort: No such file or directory
```

**Is it possible to do this in `ed`?**

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to do this requires using an external file to store the results temporarily.

```
$ cat input.txt 
13
5
29
22
45
64
17
20
69
91
$ ed input.txt 
29
1,3w !sort -n > temp.txt
8
1,3d
0r temp.txt
8
wq
29
```

Answer (score 1):

> how to do both simultaneously

You can't write lines from the text buffer to some command `stdin` and read its `stdout` back in, replacing the original lines, in one go.
`ed` was clearly not designed to do that kind of stuff... Try `vim`.
That being said, you can always use some contortions like `ed` inside `ed`, e.g. open the file, delete those lines from the text buffer, process them via another `ed` invocation (which reads from the original file not from the current buffer) whose output you then read into the buffer before the original range of lines:

```
ed -s infile
```

```
5,8d
4r ! ed -s infile<<<$'5,8w !sort -n\nq'
,p
q
```